# Multiple USB modems issue with HUB external power

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, debian, dhcp

When I connect 6 modems ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM into USB hub Terminus Technology Inc. Hub everything works fine.

Modems are detected as eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3, eth4, eth5

When one more modem is connected trough USB hub or directly into RPi the network stops working.

I also tried to connect 6 modems + 2 USB drives + 2 Phones into the HUB, but everything is working as expected.

Only issue is with 7 modems.

More information

sudo dhcpcd --version

```
dhcpcd 7.2.2
Copyright (c) 2006-2019 Roy Marples
Compiled in features: INET ARP ARPing IPv4LL INET6 DHCPv6 AUTH
```

uname -a

> Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

ip link (with 6 modems)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth-dmz: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:84:c0:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:d1:95:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
76: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
77: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
78: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
79: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
80: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
81: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ip link (with added 7th modem)

```
82: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast
state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:a0:c6:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 13fe:1e00 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Flash Drive 2 GB [ICIDU 2 GB]
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

journalctl -xe (part of it when eth6 (7th) modem is connected)

```
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=1225, bcdDevice=f1.11
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: P680A1ZTED000000CP261718HNL0ZV5JKNN7C9026142I1D&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&0
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 19d2 pid 1225: 1
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.0
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1350]: checking bus 1, device 17: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1"
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1350]: bus: 1, device: 17 was not an MTP device
May 22 15:30:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch_1-1.2.1...
May 22 15:30:31 raspberrypi usb_modeswitch[1364]: switch device 19d2:1225 on 001/017
May 22 15:30:33 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 17
May 22 15:30:33 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 18 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=1405, bcdDevice=f1.11
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=3, SerialNumber=5
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: Product: ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: P680A1ZTED010000CP261718HNL0ZV5JKNN7C9026142I1D&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&0
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.2.1:1.0 eth6: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2.1, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.2
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1375]: checking bus 1, device 18: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.1"
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi mtp-probe[1375]: bus: 1, device: 18 was not an MTP device
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: waiting for carrier
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: carrier acquired
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: IAID c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth0
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: adding address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth6.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth6.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth6.*.
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi root[1389]: usb_modeswitch: switched to 19d2:1405 on 001/018
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 22 15:30:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch_1-1.2.1.
May 22 15:30:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: offered 192.168.4.20 from 192.168.4.1
May 22 15:30:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: probing address 192.168.4.20/24
May 22 15:30:36 raspberrypi kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            CWID     USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May 22 15:30:41 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: leased 192.168.4.20 for 86400 seconds
May 22 15:30:41 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth6.IPv4 with address 192.168.4.20.
May 22 15:30:41 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: adding route to 192.168.4.0/24
May 22 15:30:41 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth6.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:41 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: adding default route via 192.168.4.1
May 22 15:30:41 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for 192.168.4.20 on eth6.IPv4.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: carrier lost
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.3.4:1.0 eth0: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.3.4, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: [sr6] scsi-1 drive
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr6
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.20.20.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 5
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth0.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.20.20 on eth0.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: deleting route to 192.168.20.0/24
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: deleting default route via 192.168.20.1
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.1.3.3.4: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: removing interface
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.3.4:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.3.4, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: waiting for carrier
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: carrier acquired
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: IAID c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth1
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: adding address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:42 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth0.*.
May 22 15:30:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 22 15:30:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.20.20
May 22 15:30:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: no IPv6 Routers available
May 22 15:30:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: probing for an IPv4LL address
May 22 15:30:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: DHCP lease expired
May 22 15:30:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: carrier lost
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.3.4:1.0 eth0: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.3.4, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.3:1.0 eth3: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.3, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.4:1.0 eth4: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.4, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.1, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.2:1.0 eth2: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.2, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: ioctl_internal_command return code = 8070000
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: Sense Key : 0x4 [current] 
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: ASC=0x0 ASCQ=0x0 
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth3.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth3.IPv4 with address 192.168.7.20.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth3.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.7.20 on eth3.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth0.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth4.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth4.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth4.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth4.IPv4 with address 192.168.10.20.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth4.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.10.20 on eth4.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 192.168.9.20.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth1.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.9.20 on eth1.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth2.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth2.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv4 with address 192.168.8.20.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth2.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.8.20 on eth2.
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: deleting address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: ipv6nd_sendadvertisement: No such device
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: deleting route to 192.168.7.0/24
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: deleting default route via 192.168.7.1
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.1.3.4.3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: dhcp_readpacket: eth0: Network is down
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: arp_read: eth0: Network is down
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.3:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.3, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: removing interface
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: carrier lost
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: deleting address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: ipv6nd_sendadvertisement: No such device
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.1.3.3.4: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: removing interface
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: ioctl_internal_command return code = 8070000
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: Sense Key : 0x4 [current] 
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: sr 6:0:0:0: ASC=0x0 ASCQ=0x0 
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: carrier lost
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: deleting address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: ipv6nd_sendadvertisement: No such device
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: deleting route to 192.168.10.0/24
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: deleting default route via 192.168.10.1
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.3.4:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.3.4, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: removing interface
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: carrier lost
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.1.3.4.2: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: deleting address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: ipv6nd_sendadvertisement: No such device
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: deleting route to 192.168.9.0/24
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: deleting default route via 192.168.9.1
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: removing interface
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: carrier lost
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.2:1.0 eth2: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.2, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: deleting address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: deleting route to 192.168.8.0/24
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: deleting default route via 192.168.8.1
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.1.3.4.4: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: removing interface
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: waiting for carrier
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.4:1.0 eth3: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.4, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: waiting for carrier
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: waiting for carrier
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: carrier acquired
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: IAID c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth5
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: adding address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.1.3.4.1: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth0.*.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: waiting for carrier
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: carrier acquired
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: IAID c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth5
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: adding address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth1.*.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: carrier acquired
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: IAID c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth5
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: adding address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth2.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth2.*.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: carrier acquired
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: IAID c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth5
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: adding address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth3.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth3.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth3.*.
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: offered 192.168.7.20 from 192.168.7.1
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: probing address 192.168.7.20/24
May 22 15:30:51 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.1.3.4.1:1.0 eth4: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1.3.4.1, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device, 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: waiting for carrier
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: carrier acquired
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: IAID c6:00:00:00
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: IAID conflicts with one assigned to eth5
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: adding address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth4.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth4.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth4.*.
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: rebinding lease of 192.168.10.20
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: rebinding lease of 192.168.7.20
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: rebinding lease of 192.168.9.20
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: rebinding lease of 192.168.8.20
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: NAK: from 192.168.10.1
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 22 15:30:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: NAK: from 192.168.20.1
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: probing address 192.168.8.20/24
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: NAK: from 192.168.9.1
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: offered 192.168.10.20 from 192.168.10.1
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: offered 192.168.20.20 from 192.168.20.1
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: probing address 192.168.10.20/24
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: offered 192.168.9.20 from 192.168.9.1
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: probing address 192.168.20.20/24
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth6.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth6.IPv6 with address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4.
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Interface eth6.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth6.IPv4 with address 192.168.4.20.
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 18
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1.2.1:1.0 eth6: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-3f980000.usb-1.2.1, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4 on eth6.
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.4.20 on eth6.
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: probing address 192.168.9.20/24
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: carrier lost
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: deleting address fe80::9e27:54b9:6fcb:1fe4
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: deleting route to 192.168.4.0/24
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: deleting default route via 192.168.4.1
May 22 15:30:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth6: removing interface
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: leased 192.168.7.20 for 86400 seconds
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.7.0/24
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.7.1
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.7.20.
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for 192.168.7.20 on eth0.IPv4.
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: leased 192.168.8.20 for 86400 seconds
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: adding route to 192.168.8.0/24
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv4 with address 192.168.8.20.
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth2: adding default route via 192.168.8.1
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth2.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:57 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for 192.168.8.20 on eth2.IPv4.
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: leased 192.168.9.20 for 86400 seconds
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth4.IPv4 with address 192.168.9.20.
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth4.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for 192.168.9.20 on eth4.IPv4.
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: adding route to 192.168.9.0/24
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth4: adding default route via 192.168.9.1
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: leased 192.168.10.20 for 86400 seconds
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth3.IPv4 with address 192.168.10.20.
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth3.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: adding route to 192.168.10.0/24
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for 192.168.10.20 on eth3.IPv4.
May 22 15:30:58 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth3: adding default route via 192.168.10.1
May 22 15:30:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: leased 192.168.20.20 for 86400 seconds
May 22 15:30:59 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 192.168.20.20.
May 22 15:30:59 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 22 15:30:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: adding route to 192.168.20.0/24
May 22 15:30:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[335]: eth1: adding default route via 192.168.20.1
May 22 15:30:59 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[349]: Registering new address record for 192.168.20.20 on eth1.IPv4.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
May 22 15:30:53 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 18
```

It is definitely the hardware issue. Maybe you need more powerful power supply.